# Workflow rule change custom picklist depending on amount field

Tags: workflow, workflow-field-update

I have a picklist with 3 value and i want to change that value depending on value from amount field.

So if amount <5 picklist value = 1

if amount >=5  and < 10 picklist value = 2

if amount >= 10 picklist value = 3

Is it possible to make with single workflow rule? It must be picklist, with text, i think. its possible. I can select only one picklist value in action.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use Process Builder to have multiple conditions like that, or even better, a Before Save Flow or Before Insert/Update Apex Trigger to avoid triggering DML triggers twice. Workflow Rules don't allow setting the value dynamically for picklist values.

Comment: Thanks. I just was wondering if there any way with workflow.

Comment: @Elrion You would need three workflow rules, so no, it is not possible.